# C# + Postgresql = caracter estranho

Tags: c#, postgresql

Saudações Galera

Estou trabalhado com C# Windows Forms e ja fiz alguns testes com postgresql usando a versao 9.1 e tudo aparentemente normal.

Porem me deparei com um banco que esta na versao 8.4, utilizando 
Encoding = "SQL_ASCII".

Dessa forma, qdo faço uma consulta os caracteres acentuados ou com cedilha
vem todos estranhos.

Como resolver isso ?

Obrigado!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os caracteres estão OK no banco?

Comment: Se usares o UTF-8 resolveria?

Comment: Então Paulo, usando o PGAdmin, no banco esta aparecendo correto, com acentos e cedilhas. Parece que é entre o C# e o postgresql. Estou usando o NPGSql para executar o CRUD

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira e usares o charset ISO-8859-1
O Charset ISO tras os caracteres que necessitas e e mais compativel que o vulgar UFT8

Comment: Então Hardcorder...o problema esta em como trazer de forma correta...sendo que no banco mostra correto...mas no c# não..!!

Comment: EU ATÉ ENCONTREI ISSO AKI:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342198/how-do-i-set-encoding-in-an-npgsqlconnection

MAS NAO ENTENDI COMO FAZER

Comment: ja sei , tem que fazer uma query ao servidor da base de dados enviando isto
SET names UTF8
OU
SET names ISO-8859-1

Comment: esse link que me mandou tambem serve, basta executar set client_encoding = 'WIN1252'     numa query do Postgresql como se fosse um comando normal

Comment: deixa eu ver se entendi...eu faço uma query enviando esse comando para o banco ?

Comment: Sim devera ser logo a primeira query depois de conectado com a base de dados!

Comment: se funcionou meta como resposta certa ;)

Comment: EXECUTEI O COMANDO

                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "set client_encoding = 'SQL_ASCII'";
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


E NADA...MANDEI UTF8, WIN1252, VOLTA COM CARACTER ESTRANHO DO MESMO JEITO

Comment: Tente executar com isto: 
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(Message);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);

Sendo a variavel "Message" os dados retirados da Base de dados